# cordova-plugin-qrscanner.QRScanner does not exists

Tags: uwp, cordova-plugins, qr-code, winjs

I  am working on QR code scanner implementation in WinJS project. I added  cordova-plugin-qrscanner in my WinJS Project which is based off of cordova.  But when I run the  project , it gives the exception cordova-plugin-qrscanner.QRScanner does not exists in Cordova.js  file. So what is the solution for this ?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Nikita. Did you find a solution? I have a similar problem...